# RestAPI : Is changing @RequestParam type from String to List<String> a backward compatible change?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, http-request-parameters

I have an API which take a @RequestParam of type String. Now I want to change the type to List. There are some existing clients who use this endpoint and request param. Will the change be considered backward compatible?

Existing : `@RequestParam("test") test: String`

New : `@RequestParam("test") test: List<String>`

Comment: Why don't you try it out yourself?

Comment: Try it and see!  (Let us know the result.)  With changing the param to plural, does the route name still make sense?

Comment: Changing the type of a `@RequestParam` from `String` to `List<String>` may not be considered backward compatible. Existing clients who use this endpoint and request parameter may encounter issues when sending requests to the updated API. One way to maintain backward compatibility is to create a new version of the API that accepts the new `List<String>` type while keeping the old version of the API that accepts the one `String`.

Comment: Write a test and you will know. Write it for the current API, change API test should still be green, if not it is not compatible.

Comment: From a REST perspective I would consider this backward compatible. When it comes to generated code based on the API, that's a different story. Parameter types of generated methods change from `String` to `List<String>` as well. However, if you add query parameters you would get the same issue.

Comment: @RobSpoor `From a REST perspective ... When it comes to generated code based on the API` then you don't do REST but just some RPC variation that you term "REST API". REST focuses on media types as contract between clients and servers in order to exchange a resource's state in a meaningful way that both can understand. A media type therefore is nothing more as a human readable description of the elements that may appear in such an exchanged payload, the context elements may appear in as well as the semantic definition of these elements.

Comment: @RomanVottner you apparently haven't worked with https://openapi-generator.tech/ yet. It generates code based on an OpenAPI spec. At least in Java, each query parameter by default becomes a method parameter. If a query parameter becomes repeatable, the type changes from the singular element type (e.g. `String`) to a list of that type (e.g. `List<String>`).

Comment: It works fine with one of the existing client and in curl. Request will be something like <url>?test=abc for existing client and <url>?test=abc,xyz or <url>?test=abc&test=xyz for new client. Both works fine with List<String> type. However, we have already published OpenAPI definition, so wanted to understand if it is the right way to change query param type from String to List<String> there as well.

Comment: @RobSpoor I have, but it has nothing to do with REST, unfortunately. It is RPC under the hood, exactly the opposite of what REST tries to achieve. The main problem is, that every guide and plenty of books just repeat what someone years ago thought is REST but isn't and therefore we have this mess of different understandings of what REST is. A whole explanation of what REST is would probably exceed the limits of an answer (!) here as well